# What does " 2>&1 " mean?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, redirect

To combine `stderr` and `stdout` into the `stdout` stream, we append this to a command:

```
2>&1
```

e.g. to see the first few errors from compiling `g++ main.cpp`:

```
g++ main.cpp 2>&1 | head
```

What does `2>&1` mean, in detail?

Comment: @dbr I don't think it's just bash - I believe it's a bourne shell thing; hence sh, bash, ksh, ash, dash, etc.

Comment: This is part of the redirection paragraph describing POSIX-compliant shells, or POSIX shell for short.  ksh is a POSIX shell for example. See:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07

Comment: This construct also works on Windows.

Comment: It's generally better doing `2>&1` than [2>/dev/null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14423442/1765658) ;-)

Comment: I thought I'd mention that `|&`  is shorthand for `2>&1 |` if you're using zsh. I can't speak to whether that applies to other bourne-like shells or if it's a zsh only feature.

Comment: @chrixian `|&` is also in Bash, great feature. Not POSIX it seems though (?)

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21/42919998#answer-42919998

Comment: @chrixian this is definitely needed in tcsh as `2>^1` doesn't work there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is /dev/null 2>&1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21)

Comment: There's also the version without any file descriptors `>&` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521596/what-does-the-01-shell-redirection-mean). How does that work?

Answer (score 3539, accepted):

File descriptor 1 is the standard output (`stdout`).
File descriptor 2 is the standard error (`stderr`).

At first, `2>1` may look like a good way to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. However, it will actually be interpreted as "redirect `stderr` to a file named `1`".

`&` indicates that what follows and precedes is a *file descriptor*, and not a filename. Thus, we use `2>&1`. Consider `>&` to be a redirect merger operator.

Comment: but then shouldn't it rather be `&2>&1`?

Comment: @Dominik: Nope, `&` is only interpreted to mean "file descriptor" in the context of redirections.  Writing `command &2>&` is parsed as `command &` and `2>&1`, i.e. "run `command` in the background, then run the command `2` and redirect its stdout into its stdout".

Comment: Why did they pick such arcane stuff as this? Just curious.

Comment: But how would you redirect stderr to a file named '&1'?

Comment: @Martin: `2>'&1'`

Comment: any idea why this interacts with grep highlighting?  `nginx -V 2>&1 | grep auth_request`, highlights the word _auth_request_ in red but  `nginx -V | grep auth_request` doesn't

Comment: so & meanings file descriptor and also go to the background??  Linux needs to stop using the same symbol too confusing!!

Comment: In case this helps for mnemonics for someone, the way I think of this connects with the C-language `&` operator, "address of" -- so, `2>&1` as a whole I read in my head as something resembling "(file descriptor) 2 redirects to the address of (file descriptor) 1".  I.e. *to where fd1 is currently going*, as of the time the shell reads that 4-character sequence.  (Because it can change.  For fun, try: `((echo 1/stdout; echo 2/stderr >&2) 2>&1 > /dev/tty) | grep --color .` -- it'll colorize what started out as standard error ("2/stderr").)

Comment: What happens if I do `2> &1` (space after `>`) instead of `2>&1`? I'm not trying it out myself over the fear of breaking stuff.

Comment: @radiantshaw It just gives an error message. In bash: `foo 2>&1` outputs "-bash: foo: command not found", and `foo 2> &1` outputs "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '&'". Shells are often picky about whitespace around symbols. @Aaron Franke Yes, `foo 2>\&1` creates a new file named "&1", containing the above error text.

Comment: Re "*Why did they pick such arcane stuff as this?*", It's actually good to use related tokens for related things. In bash, `<` redirects from a file; `<&` redirects from a fd; `<<...` redirects from a here-doc, `<(...)` redirects from a process; and `<<< ...` redirects from a string literal.

Comment: @CommaToast  Exactly. Everybody is telling me "Magic constants are bad in programming, avoid them, use names instead". And we have hard-coded file descriptor integers in the core of an operating system. Yack. Why couldn't they just use keywords like `stderr > stdout`? Another inconsistency - `>` usually means "replace". So, `2>&1` can be confused with replacing all output with error output. Why not use `>>` for appending, as we do for files? So, I vote for `stderr >> stdout`.

Comment: As a mnemonic, if you know C, following pointer arithmetics, you can think of it as "contents of 2 (`2`) go (`>`) to where 1 is, i.e. to _the memory address_ of 1 (`&1`)".

Comment: @JustAMartin you can use `2>> /dev/stdout` instead of `2>&1`. I don't think there is a way to replace the `2>>` with a keyword though since it would not be distinguishable from an argument to the command. You should use `>>` now because in this case the output file will be opened again instead of just duplicating the file descriptor, and `>` truncates the file after opening (which you don't want if stdout is redirected to a log file).

Comment: @JustAMartin They do have names. In POSIX they are defined in <unistd.h> STDIN_FILENO,(0)  STDOUT_FILENO(1)   STDERR_FILENO.(2). As for the ">" symbol, you are treating the side effect of the command as the primary. ">" redirects. Redirection to an existing file truncates and _then_ replaces. The symbol is used consistently. Also, std(in|out|err) are streams  (of bytes ). You'd expect them to mix, when you copy them together.   Nothing arcane here, no need to use magic constants, just review the definitions in the system header files. It's all there.

Comment: @CommaToast Optimization of typing & in general - it was a common trait for text oriented OSs like Linux&Unix. The syntax was meant to be as short as possible but understandable to the enlightened. Don't forget when it was created & lookup the old [ASM commands/Assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language). In the long run, this created various mischiefs like `grep` for regexp search, `mv` for rename, the infamous 1-letter options nobody knows what they do like `tar -cvzf` => in light of all of that 1=stdout and 2=stderr are things I have the least problem with :D 

Comment: @CommaToast Btw if anybody wonders `tar -cvzf` is a real-life command for "zipping" files - `tar` means "tape archiver" (that speaks for itself, yes stuff was being archived on literal (magnetic) tapes) `c` means "create a new archive", "v" means "verbose"/"verbosely list files processed", `z` goes for "filter the archive through g**z**ip" and finally `f` - "use archive file or device ARCHIVE". Nowadays these can be written as `tar --create --gzip --verbose --file=ArchiveName.tar.gz /what/to/gzip` = **please use long option names wherever possible** :-)

Comment: But @MartínFixman, why would you name a file `&1` :-D ?

Answer (score 992):

To redirect stdout to `file.txt`:

```
echo test > file.txt
```

This is equivalent to:

```
echo test 1> file.txt
```

To redirect stderr to `file.txt`:

```
echo test 2> file.txt
```

So `>&` is the syntax to **redirect** a *stream* to another *file descriptor*:

- 0 is stdin
- 1 is stdout
- 2 is stderr

To redirect stdout to stderr:

```
echo test 1>&2   # equivalently, echo test >&2
```

To redirect stderr to stdout:

```
echo test 2>&1
```

Thus, in `2>&1`:

- `2>` redirects stderr to an (unspecified) file.
- `&1` redirects stderr to stdout.

Comment: @dbr `cmd 2>&1 >>file` does not redirect stderr to the file, but `cmd >> file 2>&1` does.  Order matters.  In the first case, stderr is redirected to the stdout of the shell (possibly a tty if the command is entered interactively), and then stdout is directed to the file.  In the second case, stdout is directed to the file, and then stderr is directed to the same place.

Comment: I like the answer above, but it could be a touch clearer. "2>&1" redirects stderr to the target of stdout. So if you have something like "ls -l >> directoryContents 2>&1"  The result will be a file named directoryContents will have the contents of the working directory appended to it. If there are any errors in execution: the error messages will also be appended to the directoryContents file, as they occur.

Comment: Is `0(or 1,2)>&0(or 1,2)` like an option to control the output? Is `echo test >test.log 2>&1` same as `echo test 2>&1 >test.log`?

Comment: for completeness (as top answer) - "redirect (and append) stdout and stderr to file and terminal and get proper exit status" `command 2>&1 | tee -a file.txt`

Answer (score 432):

### Some tricks about redirection

Some syntax particularity about this may have important behaviours. There is some little samples about redirections, `STDERR`, `STDOUT`, and arguments **ordering**.

#### 1 - Overwriting or appending?

Symbol `>` means *redirection*.

- `>` means *send to as a whole completed file*, overwriting target if exist (see `noclobber` bash feature at *#3* later).
- `>>` means *send in addition to* would append to target if exist.

In any case, the file would be created if they not exist.

#### 2 - The *shell command line* is order dependent!!

For testing this, we need *a simple command which will send something on both outputs*:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 11:49 /tmp

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >/dev/null
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>/dev/null
drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 11:49 /tmp
```

(Expecting you don't have a directory named `/tnt`, of course ;). Well, we have it!!

So, let's see:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >/dev/null
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >/dev/null 2>&1

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>&1 >/dev/null
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

The last command line dumps `STDERR` to the console, and it seem not to be the expected behaviour... But...

If you want to make some *post filtering* about *standard* output, *error* output or both:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt | sed 's/^.*$/<-- & --->/'
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
<-- drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 12:02 /tmp --->

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>&1 | sed 's/^.*$/<-- & --->/'
<-- ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory --->
<-- drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 12:02 /tmp --->

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >/dev/null | sed 's/^.*$/<-- & --->/'
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >/dev/null 2>&1 | sed 's/^.*$/<-- & --->/'

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>&1 >/dev/null | sed 's/^.*$/<-- & --->/'
<-- ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory --->
```

Notice that the last command line in this paragraph is exactly same as in previous paragraph, where I wrote *seem not to be the expected behaviour* (so, this could even be an expected behaviour).

Well, there is a little tricks about redirections, for **doing different operation on both outputs**:

```sh
$ ( ls -ld /tmp /tnt | sed 's/^/O: /' >&9 ) 9>&2  2>&1  | sed 's/^/E: /'
O: drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 12:13 /tmp
E: ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

**Note**: `&9` descriptor would occur spontaneously because of `) 9>&2`.

**Addendum: nota!** With the new version of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (`>4.0`) there is a new feature and more sexy syntax for doing this kind of things:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2> >(sed 's/^/E: /') > >(sed 's/^/O: /')
O: drwxrwxrwt 17 root root 28672 Nov  5 23:00 /tmp
E: ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

And finally for such a cascading output formatting:

```sh
$ ((ls -ld /tmp /tnt |sed 's/^/O: /' >&9 ) 2>&1 |sed 's/^/E: /') 9>&1| cat -n
     1  O: drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 12:29 /tmp
     2  E: ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

**Addendum: nota!** Same new syntax, in both ways:

```sh
$ cat -n <(ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2> >(sed 's/^/E: /') > >(sed 's/^/O: /'))
     1  O: drwxrwxrwt 17 root root 28672 Nov  5 23:00 /tmp
     2  E: ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

Where `STDOUT` go through a specific filter, `STDERR` to another and finally both outputs merged go through a third command filter.

#### 2b - Using `|&` instead

Syntax `command |& ...` could be used as an *alias* for `command 2>&1 | ...`. Same rules about command line order applies. More details at [What is the meaning of operator |& in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70766960/1765658)

#### 3 - A word about `noclobber` option and `>|` syntax

That's about **overwriting**:

While `set -o noclobber` instruct bash to **not** overwrite any existing file, the `>|` syntax let you pass through this limitation:

```sh
$ testfile=$(mktemp /tmp/testNoClobberDate-XXXXXX)

$ date > $testfile ; cat $testfile
Mon Jan  7 13:18:15 CET 2013

$ date > $testfile ; cat $testfile
Mon Jan  7 13:18:19 CET 2013

$ date > $testfile ; cat $testfile
Mon Jan  7 13:18:21 CET 2013
```

The file is overwritten each time, well now:

```sh
$ set -o noclobber

$ date > $testfile ; cat $testfile
bash: /tmp/testNoClobberDate-WW1xi9: cannot overwrite existing file
Mon Jan  7 13:18:21 CET 2013

$ date > $testfile ; cat $testfile
bash: /tmp/testNoClobberDate-WW1xi9: cannot overwrite existing file
Mon Jan  7 13:18:21 CET 2013
```

Pass through with `>|`:

```sh
$ date >| $testfile ; cat $testfile
Mon Jan  7 13:18:58 CET 2013

$ date >| $testfile ; cat $testfile
Mon Jan  7 13:19:01 CET 2013
```

Unsetting this option and/or inquiring if already set.

```sh
$ set -o | grep noclobber
noclobber           on

$ set +o noclobber

$ set -o | grep noclobber
noclobber           off

$ date > $testfile ; cat $testfile
Mon Jan  7 13:24:27 CET 2013

$ rm $testfile
```

#### 4 - Last trick and more...

For redirecting **both** output from a given command, we see that a right syntax could be:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >/dev/null 2>&1
```

for this *special* case, there is a shortcut syntax: `&>` ... or `>&`

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt &>/dev/null

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt >&/dev/null
```

Nota: if **`2>&1`** exist, **`1>&2`** is a correct syntax too:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

#### 4b- Now, I will let you think about:

```sh
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>&1 1>&2  | sed -e s/^/++/
++/bin/ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
++drwxrwxrwt 193 root root 196608 Feb  9 11:08 /tmp/

$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 1>&2 2>&1  | sed -e s/^/++/
/bin/ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
drwxrwxrwt 193 root root 196608 Feb  9 11:08 /tmp/
```

#### 4c- If you're interested in *more* information

You could read the fine manual by hitting:

```sh
man -Len -Pless\ +/^REDIRECTION bash
```

in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) console ;-)

Comment: *Further reading:* If you liked this, you may apreciate: [How redirection abuse could give strange behaviours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14423442/1765658)

Comment: @fabs If you liked this, maybe would you like [Open new window for input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481412/1765658) and/or [Redirections from script himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481412/1765658)

Answer (score 190):

I found this brilliant post on redirection: *[All about redirections](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/)*

**Redirect both standard output and standard error to a file**

> $ command &>file

This one-liner uses the `&>` operator to redirect both output streams - stdout and stderr - from command to file. This is Bash's shortcut for quickly redirecting both streams to the same destination.

Here is how the file descriptor table looks like after Bash has redirected both streams:

[image]

As you can see, both stdout and stderr now point to `file`. So anything written to stdout and stderr gets written to `file`.

There are several ways to redirect both streams to the same destination. You can redirect each stream one after another:

> $ command >file 2>&1

This is a much more common way to redirect both streams to a file. First stdout is redirected to file, and then stderr is duplicated to be the same as stdout. So both streams end up pointing to `file`.

When Bash sees several redirections it processes them from left to right. Let's go through the steps and see how that happens. Before running any commands, Bash's file descriptor table looks like this:

[image]

Now Bash processes the first redirection >file. We've seen this before and it makes stdout point to file:

[image]

Next Bash sees the second redirection 2>&1. We haven't seen this redirection before. This one duplicates file descriptor 2 to be a copy of file descriptor 1 and we get:

[image]

Both streams have been redirected to file.

However be careful here! Writing

> command >file 2>&1

is not the same as writing:

> $ command 2>&1 >file

The order of redirects matters in Bash! This command redirects only the standard output to the file. The stderr will still print to the terminal. To understand why that happens, let's go through the steps again. So before running the command, the file descriptor table looks like this:

[image]

Now Bash processes redirections left to right. It first sees 2>&1 so it duplicates stderr to stdout. The file descriptor table becomes:

[image]

Now Bash sees the second redirect, `>file`, and it redirects stdout to file:

[image]

Do you see what happens here? Stdout now points to file, but the stderr still points to the terminal! Everything that gets written to stderr still gets printed out to the screen! So be very, very careful with the order of redirects!

Also note that in Bash, writing

> $ command &>file

is exactly the same as:

> $ command >&file

Comment: The last two are different if "command" ends in a number, as then that is taken as optional file descriptor for `>&`

Comment: Very nice drawing and explanation!  Could you elaborate what "duplicate" really means?  You mentioned, "This one [2>&1] duplicates file descriptor 2 to be a copy of file descriptor 1".  It sounds like stderr gets duplicated to stdout.  But if it is the case, should I also see err though `/dev/tty0`?

Comment: This is a very nice explanation with visual. If I became the one who ask this question, I will mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 128):

The numbers refer to the file descriptors (fd).

- Zero is `stdin`
- One is `stdout`
- Two is `stderr`

`2>&1` redirects fd 2 to 1.

This works for any number of file descriptors if the program uses them.

You can look at `/usr/include/unistd.h` if you forget them:

```
/* Standard file descriptors.  */
#define STDIN_FILENO    0   /* Standard input.  */
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1   /* Standard output.  */
#define STDERR_FILENO   2   /* Standard error output.  */
```

That said I have written C tools that use non-standard file descriptors for custom logging so you don't see it unless you redirect it to a file or something.

Comment: Is it okay to just use your own "non-standard file descriptors"? How do you know there isn't an open file with the same FD?

Answer (score 65):

That construct sends the standard error stream (`stderr`) to the *current* location of standard output (`stdout`) - this currency issue appears to have been neglected by the other answers.

You can redirect any output handle to another by using this method but it's most often used to channel `stdout` and `stderr` streams into a single stream for processing.

Some examples are:

```
# Look for ERROR string in both stdout and stderr.
foo 2>&1 | grep ERROR

# Run the less pager without stderr screwing up the output.
foo 2>&1 | less

# Send stdout/err to file (with append) and terminal.
foo 2>&1 |tee /dev/tty >>outfile

# Send stderr to normal location and stdout to file.
foo >outfile1 2>&1 >outfile2
```

Note that that last one will *not* direct `stderr` to `outfile2` - it redirects it to what `stdout` was when the argument was encountered (`outfile1`) and *then* redirects `stdout` to `outfile2`.

This allows some pretty sophisticated trickery.

Comment: Although that last example would be much clearer as: foo >outfile2 2>outfile1

Comment: Clearer, yes, but that wouldn't show the "positional" nature of redirection. The example is contrived since it's not usually useful to do this in a single line - the method becomes really useful when different parties are responsible for the different parts of the redirection. For example, when a script does one bit of redirection and you run it with another bit.

Comment: I just realized that the last example also resolves a long standing confusion I had regarding why this: `some_program 2>&1 > /dev/null` does not work like this: `some_program > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Your comment about the last example is worth its letters in gold :-) I never thought that these redirectional arguments are positional... I think this is pretty important to know.

Answer (score 65):

I found this very helpful if you are a beginner read [this](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/)

Update:
In Linux or Unix System there are two places programs send output to: **Standard output (stdout) and Standard Error (stderr)**.You can redirect these output to any file.
Like if you do this 
`ls -a > output.txt`

Nothing will be printed in console all output **(stdout)** is redirected to output file.

And if you try print the content of any file that does not exits means output will be an error like if you print test.txt that not present in current directory
`cat test.txt > error.txt`

Output will be

```
cat: test.txt :No such file or directory
```

But error.txt file will be empty because we redirecting the stdout to a file not stderr. 
so we need file descriptor( A file descriptor is nothing more than a positive integer that represents an open file. You can say descriptor is unique id of file) to tell shell which type of output we are sending to file .In Unix /Linux system **1 is for stdout and 2 for stderr**.

so now if you do this 
 `ls -a 1> output.txt` means you are sending Standard output (stdout) to output.txt. 
and if you do this 
`cat test.txt 2> error.txt` means you are sending Standard Error (stderr) to error.txt . 
`&1` is used to reference the value of the file descriptor 1 (stdout).

Now to the point `2>&1` means “Redirect the stderr to the same place we are redirecting the stdout”
Now you can do this 
<br

`cat maybefile.txt > output.txt 2>&1` 

 both Standard output (stdout) and Standard Error (stderr) will redirected to output.txt.

Thanks to [Ondrej K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9288200/ondrej-k) for pointing out

Comment: +1 for "&1 is used to reference the value of the file descriptor 1 (stdout).". I always wondered why it wasn't just `2>1`

Answer (score 28):

2 is the console standard error.

1 is the console standard output.

This is the standard Unix, and Windows also follows the POSIX.

E.g. when you run

```
perl test.pl 2>&1
```

the standard error is redirected to standard output, so you can see both outputs together:

```
perl test.pl > debug.log 2>&1
```

After execution, you can see all the output, including errors, in the debug.log.

```
perl test.pl 1>out.log 2>err.log
```

Then standard output goes to out.log, and standard error to err.log.

I suggest you to try to understand these.

Comment: The second sample is wrong: as order precedence *STDERR* is redirected to *STDOUT*, only default *STDOUT* will be written to *debug.log* (not *STDERR*) see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/1765658) (the paragraph #2)! To ensure **both** to be redirected to same file, you have to invert redirections directives: `perl test.pl > debug.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 25):

`2>&1` is a POSIX shell construct. Here is a breakdown, token by token:

---

`2`: "**Standard error**" output file descriptor.

`>&`: [**Duplicate an Output File Descriptor**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) operator (a variant of [**Output Redirection**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02) operator `>`). Given `[x]>&[y]`, the file descriptor denoted by `x` is made to be a copy of the output file descriptor `y`.

`1` "**Standard output**" output file descriptor.

The expression `2>&1` copies file descriptor `1` to location `2`, so any output written to `2` ("standard error") in the execution environment goes to the same file originally described by `1` ("standard output").

---

Further explanation:

[**File Descriptor**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_166): "A per-process unique, non-negative integer used to identify an open file for the purpose of file access."

**Standard output/error**: Refer to the following note in the [Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) section of the shell documentation:

> Open files are represented by decimal numbers starting with zero. The largest possible value is implementation-defined; however, all implementations shall support at least 0 to 9, inclusive, for use by the application. These numbers are called "file descriptors". The values 0, 1, and 2 have special meaning and conventional uses and are implied by certain redirection operations; they are referred to as standard input, standard output, and standard error, respectively. Programs usually take their input from standard input, and write output on standard output. Error messages are usually written on standard error. The redirection operators can be preceded by one or more digits (with no intervening  characters allowed) to designate the file descriptor number.

Answer (score 20):

To answer your question: It takes any error output (normally sent to stderr) and writes it to standard output (stdout).

This is helpful with, for example 'more' when you need paging for all output. Some programs like printing usage information into stderr.

To help you remember

- 1 = standard output (where programs print normal output)
- 2 = standard error (where programs print errors)

"2>&1" simply points everything sent to stderr, to stdout instead.

I also recommend reading [this post on error redirecting](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) where this subject is covered in full detail.

Answer (score 11):

From a programmer's point of view, it means precisely this:

```
dup2(1, 2);
```

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2).

Understanding that `2>&1` is a *copy* also explains why ...

```
command >file 2>&1
```

... is not the same as ...

```
command 2>&1 >file
```

The first will send both streams to `file`, whereas the second will send errors to `stdout`, and ordinary output into `file`.

Answer (score 9):

People, always remember *paxdiablo*'s hint about the **current** location of the redirection target... It **is** important.

My personal mnemonic for the `2>&1` operator is this:

- Think of `&` as meaning `'and'` or `'add'` (the character is an *ampers*-***and***, isn't it?)
- So it becomes: *'redirect `2` (stderr) to where `1` (stdout) already/currently is and **add** both streams'*.

The same mnemonic works for the other frequently used redirection too, `1>&2`:

- Think of `&` meaning `and` or `add`... (you get the idea about the ampersand, yes?)
- So it becomes:  *'redirect `1` (stdout) to where `2` (stderr) already/currently is and **add** both streams'*.

And always remember: you have to read chains of redirections 'from the end', from right to left (**not** from left to right).

Answer (score 9):

> ### Redirecting Input
>
> Redirection of input causes the file whose name
>   results from the expansion of word to be opened for reading on file
>   descriptor n, or the standard  input (file descriptor 0) if n is
>   not specified.
>
> The general format for redirecting input is:
>
> ```
> [n]<word
> ```
>
> ### Redirecting Output
>
> Redirection of output causes the file whose
>   name results from the expansion of word to be opened for writing on
>   file descriptor n, or the standard output (file  descriptor 1) if n
>   is not specified. If the file does not exist it is    created; if it
>   does exist it is truncated to zero size.
>
> The general format for redirecting output is:
>
> ```
> [n]>word
> ```
>
> ### Moving File Descriptors
>
> The redirection operator,
>
> ```
> [n]<&digit-
> ```
>
> moves the file descriptor digit to file descriptor n, or the
>   standard  input (file  descriptor 0) if n is not specified.
>   digit is closed after being duplicated to n.
>
> Similarly, the redirection operator
>
> ```
> [n]>&digit-
> ```
>
> moves the file descriptor digit to file descriptor n, or the
>   standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified.

### Ref:

```
man bash
```

Type `/^REDIRECT` to locate to the `redirection` section, and learn more...

An online version is here: *[3.6 Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)*

#### PS:

Lots of the time, `man` was the powerful tool to learn Linux.

Answer (score 9):

`unix_commands 2>&1`

This is used to print errors to the terminal.

- When *errors* are produced, they are written to the "standard error" buffer at memory address `&2`, and `2` references and streams from that buffer.
- When *outputs* are produced, they are written to the "standard output" buffer at memory address `&1`, and `1` references and streams from that buffer.

So going back to the command. Anytime the program `unix_commands` produces an error, it writes that into the *errors* buffer. So we create a pointer to that buffer `2`, and redirect `>` the errors into the *outputs* buffer `&1`. At this point we're done, because anything in the outputs buffer is read and printed by the terminal.

Answer (score 8):

Provided that `/foo` does not exist on your system and `/tmp` does…

```
$ ls -l /tmp /foo
```

will print the contents of `/tmp` and print an error message for `/foo`

```
$ ls -l /tmp /foo >/dev/null
```

will send the contents of `/tmp` to `/dev/null` and print an error message for `/foo`

```
$ ls -l /tmp /foo 1>/dev/null
```

will do exactly the same (note the **1**)

```
$ ls -l /tmp /foo 2>/dev/null
```

will print the contents of `/tmp` and send the error message to `/dev/null`

```
$ ls -l /tmp /foo 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

will send both the listing as well as the error message to `/dev/null`

```
$ ls -l /tmp /foo >/dev/null 2>&1
```

is shorthand

Answer (score 5):

This is just like passing the error to the stdout or the terminal.

That is, `cmd` is not a command:

```
$cmd 2>filename
cat filename

command not found
```

The error is sent to the file like this:

```
2>&1
```

Standard error is sent to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

0 for input, 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr.

**One Tip**:
`somecmd >1.txt 2>&1` is correct, while `somecmd 2>&1 >1.txt` is totally **wrong** with no effect!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand this in terms of pipe.

```
$ (whoami;ZZZ) 2>&1  | cat
logan
ZZZ: command not found
```

As you can see both stdout and stderr of LHS of pipe is fed into the RHS (of pipe).

This is the same as

```
$ (whoami;ZZZ) |& cat
logan
ZZZ: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `1>&2` cannot be used interchangeably with `2>&1`.

Imagine your command depends on piping, for example:
`docker logs 1b3e97c49e39 2>&1 | grep "some log"`
grepping will happen across both `stderr` and `stdout` since `stderr` is basically merged into `stdout`.

However, if you try:
`docker logs 1b3e97c49e39 1>&2 | grep "some log"`,
grepping will not really search anywhere at all because Unix pipe is connecting processes via connecting `stdout | stdin`, and `stdout` in the second case was redirected to `stderr` in which Unix pipe has no interest.

Comment: Your grep example only demonstrates how grep does not get stderr as input in Unix pipe. This does not however show that `1>&2` and `2>&1` cannot be used in an interchangable way. Do you have any other examples that would clarify your initial thesis?